# Databound windows phone panorama with MVVM design

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, mvvm, panorama-control

Please assist with MVVM design/understanding problem.

Given that we have a Windows Phone app with following UI structure:

**MainPage.xaml** body:

```
<views:PanoramaView/>

DataContext is set via MVVM Light view-model locator to a static MainViewModel class instance.
```

**Views/PanoramaView.xaml** body:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:PanoramaViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <controls:Panorama Background="{Binding PanoramaBackgroundBrush}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding PanoramaItems}"
                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource panoramaItemTemplate}"
                           />
</StackPanel>
```

At that point I have stumbled upon a question - **What should I do in case I want all my PanoramaItems to be comprised of a different user controls?** If I define a panorama item template, I doom all of them to be alike. But my intention is to have serveral, compeltely different panorama items. I wanted to have a class (presumably `PanoramaViewModel`) that would allow me control which panorama items are displayed at a given moment of time.

So there has to be a way for me to still stick to MVVM, but to be able to instantiate new Views(Panorama Items) and inject them into a `PanoramaItems` collection of my `PanoramaViewModel`. Where and how do I do that?

Comment: MVVM have nothing to do with this.

Comment: I assumed that if I need to display different views based on a view model type found in Items collection of Panorama control, then it has to do with MVVM. But, as I said, I am unaware of how to work around such requirement, so you may be correct, and this questions falls out of MVVM scope.

Comment: Thank you. I am working on it.

Comment: @Claus, why bother replying if you are just going to dismiss his question with a borderline destructive response and offer nothing constructive in return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define resource key to define a data template with view setter for the view item being rendered for the different view model class types, and derive VM classes from a common base class (PanoramaViewModel, i.e)

Answer (score 0):

In WPF I should have use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to work around my design problem. 
Since Windows Phone apps are more like Silverlight, I can implement it myself. A good example of how is in [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/09/28/datatemplateselector-in-silverlight.aspx) article and [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/190667.aspx) silverlight.net forum thread.