# Bind various panaroma/pivot items using MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, panorama-control

could someone help me with design/understanding the problem: what I need to achieve is page with Panorama/Pivot control, where its items (panos/pivots) will be set via binding, using standard MVVM pattern. Problem is I need to have different content (different user controls) on each pano/pivot, that means If I define a panorama/pivot item template, I doom all of them to be alike, which is not what I want.

I found this question here already asked: [Databound windows phone panorama with MVVM design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373410/databound-windows-phone-panorama-with-mvvm-design) but its still not clear to me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a dynamic page count on panorama/pivot you could use selector to choose what template is right according to your content.

[Implementing DataTemplateSelector](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector)

Also, [Data Binding Pivot to MVVM](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/data-binding-pivot-control-wp7-mvvm/) may help you too

Answer (score 1):

You could add a dependency property to the user control that you want to use as a data template, a dependency property named "Type" for example and depending on that property you can change the layout of your user control (data template) - for example you could have multiple grids inside your user control and you could show and hide them depending on the type.